# NullPointerException source not found

Tags: java

I have already posted the same problem twice with two different questions since according to the comments it was not clear enough or moreover complete in terms of information so I modified the first one and here it is.

My application works well in netbeans, it does not report any errors. but after creating an installer (with launch4j and innoSetup), the application reports a NullPointerException whose source I don't know. need help please. Thank you

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connecteur connexion = new Connecteur();
    Statement stm;
    ResultSet resultat;
    public static String Id ="";
    
    public Login() {
        initComponents();
    }

   
                          

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
        
        try {
   (here)stm =connexion.obtenirconnexion().createStatement();
            System.out.println(stm);
            ResultSet resultat = stm.executeQuery("select * from Techniciens where UserName ='"+UserName.getText().toString()+"'");
            
            Id = resultat.getString("IdTech");
            
            if ((resultat.getString("UserName").equals(UserName.getText().toString())) && (resultat.getString("Password").equals(Password.getText().toString()))){
            
            Principale P = new Principale();
            P.setVisible(true);
            this.hide();
            }
   
            
        } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Compte invalide");
            
        }
        finally{
            try{
                stm.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }
        } 

        
    }
```

class conneteur:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class Connecteur {
    Connection con ;
    public Connecteur(){
        try{
            
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
           System.err.println(e);
          //message d'erreur
        }
        try{
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\DataBase\\IPM.db");
            System.out.println("connected");
            
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
            
        }
    }
    Connection obtenirconnexion(){return con;}
}
```

exception:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1288]
    (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Users\Zouzou>cd desktop

    C:\Users\Zouzou\Desktop>java -jar "Logiciel_IPM.jar"
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\DataBase\IPM.db
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at logiciel_ipm.Login.jButton1ActionPerformed(Login.java:98)
        at logiciel_ipm.Login.access$000(Login.java:11)
        at logiciel_ipm.Login$1.actionPerformed(Login.java:49)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown 
        Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown 
        Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown 
        Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There’s no null pointer exception. The exception explains what’s wrong

Comment: (just to make things even simpler: org.sqlite.JDBC not found)

Comment: Are you sure that you're including your external dependencies to your launcher as well? Some buzzword could be the difference between slim and fat jar.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` is merely a side effect of you ignoring the `ClassNotFoundException` and `SQLException` which occurred during startup.  Your application is not addressing these critical exceptions which prevents it from starting up properly.  If you cannot recover from an Exception then you should either percolate it for someone else to handle or terminate processing.

Resolve why the `ClassNotFoundException` is occurring and the `SQLException` and `NullPointerException` will likely go away.

Comment: **DO NOT IGNORE EXCEPTIONS.** If DriverManager.getConnection fails, **do not continue.**  Your program **cannot function properly** without a database connection, so the correct thing to do if you encounter an SQLException is **terminate your program.**  The best way to do this is to remove all try/catch statements from the Connecteur class, and add `throws SQLException` to the Connecteur constructor.  Class.forName is not needed, so you can remove that line entirely.

Comment: I followed your advice concerning throws and blocks try and I have an exception which says that the connection variable is null and yet it should not since in the class connector I returned con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc: sqlite:C:\\DataBase\\IPM.db")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the NPE problem. I forgot to instantiate my statement variable. `this.connexion = new Connecteur();`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:C:\DataBase\IPM.db
```

You didn’t package the jdbc driver you use.